# Insert object in multidimensional array in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multidimensional-array

Okay, noob question! I want to add data dynamically to a two dimensional array (basically, a multidimensional vector in C++ terms). I am trying to use the addObject: atIndex method but it seems to add the object to all the columns in the 2D array and not the specific column my index specifies. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

2D Array initialization:

```
for (NSInteger i=0; i<numberOfChannels; i++) {
        [allChannelArrays addObject:newChannelArray]; //newChannelArray is an empty array
    }
```

Method adding data:

```
-(void)updatePlot:(double)arrayvalue :(CPTPlot *)plot :(NSUInteger)i {
    static int j=0;
    [[allChannelArrays objectAtIndex:j] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:(arrayvalue + j*0.001)]]; //Here lies the problem!
    NSLog(@"number of elements in 1D array: %d", [allChannelArrays[j] count]);
    [plot insertDataAtIndex:[allChannelArrays[j] count]-1 numberOfRecords:1];
    j++;
    if (j>=self.totalChannels.numberOfChannels) {
        j=0;
    }
}
```

Here are the screenshots showing the values in the array:

Before execution of statement (Note 0 objects in all columns of allChannelsArray):

[image]

After execution of statement (Note 1 object each in all columns of allChannelsArray):
[image]

I also tried the following methods:
1. Using insertObject: atIndex method and passing the last element of respective columns.
2. Since addObject seemed to affect all columns, I let that happen and tried to then re-assign a value to just one location using this-

```
allChannelArrays [j] [([allChannelArrays[j] count]-1)] = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(arrayvalue + j*0.001)];
```

But even the second method changed values in all columns.

I am sure that I am making some simple mistake but I can't figure it out. Is this even the right way to initialize a 2D array and add data? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the same array to all 4 indices of your outer array rather than allocating a new one each time.

Your initialisation code should be

```
for (NSInteger i=0; i<numberOfChannels; i++) {
    [allChannelArrays addObject:[NSMutableArray new]]; 
}
```